# How can I set the upload file max size limit in meteor?

Tags: meteor

everyone.

Here is my code(coffeescript):

```
fd = new FormData()
fd.append 'videoId', videoId
fd.append 'audioDataURL', audioDataURL
fd.append 'videoDataURL', videoDataURL
fd.append 'userId', Meteor.userId()

HTTP.call 'POST', '/upload/', 
    content: fd
, (result) ->
       console.log 'upload video successfully!'
```

When I use HTTP.post to POST form data, the server always throw the following error:

`Error: maxFieldsSize 2097152 exceeded.`

How can I set the upload file max size limit ?

Thanks!